# Delete all liveData and Observer on Spinner selected

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

**Scenario**
I have Spinner and RecyclerView. The spinner has three different options **VIP Users** ,**New Users** , **High Score Users**. In myViewModel,

```
private liveData<ArrayList<User>> userList;
public void init(int position){
switch (position){
  case 0: 
    userList = myRepo.getInstance().getVipUser();
  break;

  case 1:
  userList = myRepo.getInstance().getNewUser();
 break;

 case 2:
 userList = myRepo.getInstance().getHScoreUser();
 break;
 }}

 public LiveData<ArrayList<User>> getUserList(){return userList;}
```

And in myFragment,

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
myViewModel.getUserList().removeObserver(getViewLifeCycleOwner ());
myViewModel.init(pos);

myViewModel.getUserList().observe(getViewLifeCycleOwner(), 
 userList->{
      //Attach userList to RecyclerView
          }
 }
```

Everything went fine. But When I select another options on Spinner. Example when I change **VIP user** to **High Score User**, livdata observe old data too. If user1,2,3 are VIP users and user4,5 are high score users, all 5 user are displaying in High score users instead of showing user4,5 only.

So I want to delete previous data from livedata when Spinner Selection change. Is there some way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

what I would use is `switchMap` in livedata. So basically I would have something like this:

```java
MutableLiveData userTypeLiveData = MutableLiveData<Int>;
LiveData userLiveData = Transformations.switchMap(userTypeLiveData, userType ->

    myRepo.getInstance().getUsersByType(userType);
)

void selectUser(int userType) {
     this.userTypeLiveData.setValue(userType);
}
```

And I would add switch in Repository class

Comment: **userIdLiveData** is what type of LiveData?

Comment: Sorry, I edited name of the answer and didn't change the name everywhere, look now :)